# Definition of supremum clarification (Abbott - Understanding Analysis Lemma 1.3.8)

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

In [Abbott, Understanding Analysis](http://community.middlebury.edu/%7Eabbott/UA/UA.html) page 17 we have the following:

**Lemma 1.3.8.** Assume $s \in \mathbb R$ is an upper bound for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$. Then, $s = \sup A$ if and only if, for every choice of $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element $a \in A$ satisfying $s-\epsilon < a$.

But if we take $A = [1, 2]$ then $s = \sup A =2$ and choose $\epsilon = 5 > 0$, say, then the lemma fails since $s-\epsilon = 2-5=-3 \notin A$?

Comment: You're not applying the Lemma.  You're using equality rather than less than.  Does $A$ have any elements that are greater than $-3$?

Answer (score 1):

$s-\epsilon$ need not be in $A$. The Lemma says that the is an element of $A$ that is bigger than $s-\epsilon$, although $s$ is bigger than (or equal) to all elements of $A$.
In your example, where we take $\epsilon=5$ all the elements of $A$ are bigger than $s-\epsilon=2-5=-3$. In fact, for every choice of $\epsilon>0$, the element $2\in A$ is bigger than $s-\epsilon=2-\epsilon$.
Every number $s'$ greater than 2 cannot be the supremum, since we can take $\epsilon=\frac{s'-2}{2}$ so $s'-\epsilon=\frac{2+s'}{2}>2$, so for this choice of $\epsilon$, all the elements of $A$ are less than $s'-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

$-3\notin A$ is correct but it is no problem.

Now, $A=[1,2]$ and then $\sup A=2$.

Thus from the lemma, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists a\in A$ s.t. $2-\epsilon<a.$

Especially, you are considering the case $\epsilon=5$.

Then there exists $a\in A$ s.t. $2-5<a$, i.e., $-3<a.$

Therefore, $a\in A=[1,2]$ and $-3<a$. No contradiction arises.